React-native js bundle including relative paths
when I run command npx react-native bundle which creates me RN .js bundle files, in those files all import references have a relative path which starts ".__location="/Users/ACTUAL_DEV_USERNAME/Desktop/GitHUB/...". Is it possible to configure my babel/tsconfig to have all the paths in these bundle files start with the root of the project?
My babel.config.js:
module.exports = (api) => {
    let prodEnv = api.cache(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');
    let config = {
        presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
        plugins: [
            'jsx-control-statements',
            [
                'module-resolver',
                {
                    root: ['./'],
                    alias: {
                        images: './images/',
                        components: './components/',
                    },
                },
            ],
            'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
        ],
    };

    config.plugins = [...config.plugins, 'import-graphql'];

    if (prodEnv) {
        config.plugins = [...config.plugins, 'transform-remove-console'];
    }

    return config;
};

My tsconfig:
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "jsx": "react",
        "target": "esnext",
        "lib": ["esnext"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "images/*": ["./images/*"],
            "components/*": ["./components/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "babel.config.js",
        "metro.config.js",
        "jest.config.js",
        "ios",
        "android"
    ],
    "include": ["*.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}

The problem which I am trying to resolve is: not including dev usernames into final prod build logic, so the bundles created by any user would match ideally.
Thanks in advance
